# Spring data mongo not binding some parameters

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I have a spring mongo repository with the following method

```
@Query(value = "{storeId: ?0, code: ?1, $or: [ { campaignId: ?2}, {campaignId: ''}, {campaignId: null}], $or: [ {$and: [ {'effectiveDate.from': { $lte: ?3}}, {'effectiveDate.to': { $gte: ?3}} ]}, {$and: [ {'effectiveDate.from': { $lte: ?4}}, {'effectiveDate.to': { $gte: ?4}} ]}]}")
List<GiftCard> findByGiftCardExisting(
        String storeId, String code, String campaignId, LocalDateTime from, LocalDateTime to);
```

The query has been tested using mongo's console. 
However, when running the application, I get a JSONParseException. After some digging, I have noted that parameter $2 was not bound as expected.

```
{storeId: "L_STORE", code: "TESTE1", $or: [ { campaignId: ?2}, {campaignId: ''}, {campaignId: null}], $or: [ {$and: [ {'effectiveDate.from': { $lte: { "$date" : "2017-04-03T03:00:00.000Z"}}}, {'effectiveDate.to': { $gte: { "$date" : "2017-04-03T03:00:00.000Z"}}} ]}, {$and: [ {'effectiveDate.from': { $lte: { "$date" : "2017-04-03T03:00:00.000Z"}}}, {'effectiveDate.to': { $gte: { "$date" : "2017-04-03T03:00:00.000Z"}}} ]}]}
```

The remaining parameters are working as expected. Can someone please point what's wrong?

Comment: What happens if you simplify your @Query to use just one campaignId instead of 3?  I wonder if spring data is getting confused there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have couple of problems with your query.

You are missing the parenthesis around the `$or` operator and the other one is you have to use explicit `$and` when you use specify multiple expression with same (`$or`) operator.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/#and-queries-with-multiple-expressions-specifying-the-same-operator

Try

```
@Query(value = "{storeId: ?0, code: ?1, $and:[{$or: [ { campaignId: ?2}, {campaignId: ''}, {campaignId: null}]}, {$or: [ {$and: [ {'effectiveDate.from': { $lte: ?3}}, {'effectiveDate.to': { $gte: ?3}} ]}, {$and: [ {'effectiveDate.from': { $lte: ?4}}, {'effectiveDate.to': { $gte: ?4}} ]}]}]}")
List<GiftCard> findByGiftCardExisting(
    String storeId, String code, String campaignId, LocalDateTime from, LocalDateTime to);
```

Comment: thank you very much. I would never note the missing `$and` operator.

Comment: The issue with binding the same placeholder has been fixed now. Try spring mongo version 1.10.1 and after. Updated the answer. Here is the info. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43306460/spring-mongorepository-query-jsonparseexception/43311584#43311584.