# Spring MongoRepository @Query JSONParseException

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, mongorepository

I have the following MongoDB entities:

```
public class Player {

    @Id 
    private String id;

    private String username;

    private int rating;

    private boolean active;
}

public class Match {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @DBRef
    private Player playerOne;

    @DBRef
    private Player playerTwo;
}
```

I try to get all Player's matches. It means that e.g  I have *current player* and matches list should be returned for matches when playerOne == *current player* **or** playerTwo == *current player*. I used MongoRepository for this:

```
public interface MatchRepository extends MongoRepository<Match, String> {

    @Query(value = "{'$or': [{'playerOne.id': ?0}, {'playerTwo.id': ?0}]}")
    List<Match> findByPlayerId(String playerId);
}
```

When I've executed *findByPlayerId* method I retrieved below error:

`Caused by: com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException: 
{'$or': [{'playerOne.id': "58ea191756a4302290fff9b1"}, {'playerTwo.id': "58ea191756a4302290fff9b1"0}]}`

I noticed strange `0` character on the end of error message: `"0}]}`

I also made some workaround and pass the same `player.id` as a second method argument and it works fine:

```
@Query(value = "{'$or': [{'playerOne.id': ?0}, {'playerTwo.id': ?1}]}")
List<Match> findByPlayerId(String playerId, String palyerId2);
```

Do you have any ideas why first approach returns JSONParseException?

Comment: Which version of spring boot or spring-data-mongodb are you using?

Comment: I use spring boot 1.5.1.RELEASE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the ticket covering that change. Its been resolved and released. Try boot version 1.5.2 and after or spring mongo 1.10.1 and after.

https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1603.

Comment: Perfect, after upgrade to 1.5.2 it works as expected. Thank you for help.